# The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated

Tags: cordova, gradle, build.gradle

When executing the command: I see the information and after 30 seconds an error.

> The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
>   Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead. at build_cpi2ciq0xq9tufpedr81p3j2s.run(PATH\src-cordova\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:148);

How to fix it?

Comment: Another mistake:
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of:

```
task << {
   println "Action!"
}
```

use:

```
task {
   doLast {
      println "Action!"
   }
}
```

`<<` under the hood calls `leftShift` which as you can see was deprecated and removed.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now a new problem: publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

Comment: @АлександрМиронов it seems to be a separate problem and be solved in another question. It also seems that google might be helpful in this case.

Comment: @Opal, please, with and where is this file, soo I can change it???

Comment: Sorry, which file?

Comment: @Opal where I can do the configure: task {
   doLast {
      println "Action!"
   }
} ???

Comment: **Here** in my **cordova project** I am running "gradlew" command !